# Flutter - How to broadcast in GetX?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a requirement: I have A, B, C, D, E.... multi pages in App. And now When I click a button in Page E, change the keyword, All page's controller will get this notification and use this changed keyword to query the web server then update page's UI.

I know 'EventBus' can achieve this goal. Do you know how to do in GetX.

Comment: you can check and adapt this package to your project https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus

Answer (score 0):

You can use Obx() widget. Then you can use FutureBuilder inside it for webserver requests.